# Why is my pygame window not opening after I close another window and producing an unexpected error?

Tags: python, pygame

so here is my code:

```
import math
import random
import time
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
import pygame_functions
from pygame_functions import *

# Initialises pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()

#Difficulty
num_of_enemies = 0
set_positive_enemyX_change = 0
set_negative_enemyX_change = 0

#Menu
def menu(num_of_enemies, set_positive_enemyX_change, set_negative_enemyX_change):
    screenSize(1000, 1000)
    #                 text, fontSize, xpos, ypos, fontColour='black', font='Arial', background='clear'
    difficultyLabel = makeLabel("Which level of difficulty would you like to play on ?<br>The types are :<br>- easy<br>- medium<br>- hard<br>- insane", 40, 10, 10, "blue", "Agency FB", "yellow")
    showLabel(difficultyLabel)

    #                      x, y, width, case, text, max length, fontsize
    inputBox = makeTextBox(10, 270, 300, 0, "Enter difficulty level here", 0, 24)
    showTextBox(inputBox)
    difficultyInput = textBoxInput(inputBox)

    easyLabel = makeLabel("easy settings applied", 40, 20, 310, "white", "Agency FB", )
    mediumLabel = makeLabel("medium settings applied", 40, 20, 310, "white", "Agency FB",)
    hardLabel = makeLabel("hard settings applied", 40, 20, 310, "white", "Agency FB", )
    insaneLabel = makeLabel("insane settings applied", 40, 20, 310, "white", "Agency FB")
    startingLabel = makeLabel("Starting game", 40, 40, 310, "red", "Agency FB")

    if difficultyInput == "easy":
        showLabel(easyLabel)
        num_of_enemies = 4
        set_positive_enemyX_change = 1
        set_negative_enemyX_change = -1
        end()
    if difficultyInput == "medium":
        showLabel(mediumLabel)
        num_of_enemies = 6
        set_positive_enemyX_change = 1.5
        set_negative_enemyX_change = -1.5
        end()
        showLabel(startingLabel)
    if difficultyInput == "hard":
        showLabel(hardLabel)
        num_of_enemies = 7
        set_positive_enemyX_change = 2
        set_negative_enemyX_change = -2
        end()
    if difficultyInput == "insane":
        showLabel(insaneLabel)
        num_of_enemies = 8
        set_positive_enemyX_change = 3.5
        set_negative_enemyX_change = -3.5
        end()
    else:
        menu(num_of_enemies, set_positive_enemyX_change, set_negative_enemyX_change)

menu(num_of_enemies, set_positive_enemyX_change, set_negative_enemyX_change)

# Creates the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# Background
background = pygame.image.load('hyperspace.png')

# Sound
mixer.music.load("background.wav")
mixer.music.play(-1)

global deathSound
global liveLossSound

liveLossSound = mixer.Sound("Death sound in Minecraft.wav")
deathSound = mixer.Sound("Pacman-death.wav")

liveLossSoundBoolean = True
deathSoundBoolean = True

# Caption and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load('player.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0

# Enemy
enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []


for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load('enemy.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 736))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 150))
    enemyX_change.append(2)
    enemyY_change.append(20)

# Bullet

# Ready - You can't see the bullet on the screen
# Fire - The bullet is currently moving

bulletImg = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 5
bullet_state = "ready"

# Score
score_value = 0
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

textSX = 10
textSY = 10

# Lives
lives_value = 3

textLX = 650
textLY = 10



# Game Over
over_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 64)


def show_score(x, y):
    score = font.render("Score : " + str(score_value), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(score, (x, y))

def show_lives(x, y):
    lives = font.render("Lives : " + str(lives_value), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(lives, (x, y))


def game_over_text():
    over_text = over_font.render("GAME OVER", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(over_text, (200, 250))

def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))


def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemyImg[i], (x, y))

def play_liveLossSound():
    liveLossSound.play()
    liveLossSoundBoolean = False

def play_deathSound(deathSound):
    deathSound.play()
    deathSoundBoolean = False

def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 16, y + 10))

def isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemyX - bulletX, 2) + (math.pow(enemyY - bulletY, 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False


# Game Loop
running = True
while running:

    # RGB = Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # Background Image
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

         # if keystroke is pressed check whether its right or left
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -2  #5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 2  #5
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bullet_state is "ready":
                    bulletSound = mixer.Sound("laser.wav")
                    bulletSound.play()
                    # Gets the current x co-ordinate of the spaceship
                    bulletX = playerX
                    fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

    # 5 = 5 + -0.1 -> 5 = 5 - 0.1
    # 5 = 5 + 0.1

    playerX += playerX_change
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736

    # Enemy Movement
    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        if enemyY[i] > 200:  # was 440
            lives_value -= 1
            show_lives(textLX, textLY)
            pygame.display.update()
            if lives_value < 1:
                for j in range(num_of_enemies):
                    enemyY[j] = -2000
                if deathSoundBoolean:
                    play_deathSound(deathSound)
                game_over_text()
                time.sleep(5)
                running = False
            elif lives_value >= 1:
                if liveLossSoundBoolean:
                    play_liveLossSound()
                enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 736)
                enemyY[i] = random.randint(50, 150)

        # Bouncing enemies off of edge of window // enemy speed
        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
        if enemyX[i] <= 0:
            enemyX_change[i] = set_positive_enemyX_change
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
        elif enemyX[i] >= 736:
            enemyX_change[i] = set_negative_enemyX_change
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]

        # Collision
        collision = isCollision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
        if collision:
            explosionSound = mixer.Sound("explosion.wav")
            explosionSound.play()
            bulletY = 480
            bullet_state = "ready"
            score_value += 1
            enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 736)
            enemyY[i] = random.randint(50, 150)

        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)

    # Bullet Movement
    if bulletY <= 0:
        bulletY = 480
        bullet_state = "ready"

    if bullet_state is "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change

    player(playerX, playerY)
    show_score(textSX, textSY)
    show_lives(textLX, textLY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I am using this library from github https://github.com/StevePaget/Pygame_Functions/wiki ( i only used methods from this library from lines 18-63 )

I am trying to load the pygame window for my actual game after ( lines 66+) after the menu() function has finished

The problem is that I am getting these errors for no apparent reason, I am most concerned with the video initialisation error as it seems irrelevant to my program, the other errors I just do not understand as my program should logically work, as far as I understand.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You get the error `video system not initialized` because you called `pygame.quit()` beforehand (it's called by the `end()` function).

It even [says so in the wiki](https://github.com/StevePaget/Pygame_Functions/wiki/end) of the library you use:

> `end()`
>
> **Note**: Any graphical commands which appear after the window has closed will raise an error.

There's usually no reason to call `pygame.quit()` at all, so I suggest to just remove it.

If you really want to close a window and open a new one, you can initialze the pygame module again (`pygame.init()`) and create a new window (`pygame.display.set_mode(...)`). But usually you're better of to restructure your code.

Comment: Hey thanks for you reply, I read the wiki but I did not really consider pygame.quit() as a graphical function so I see my error there, I am quite new to pygame so could you give me any advice on how to start the window of my actual game directly after the window in menu() has finished executing ? As even after some research I could not find out how to create text boxes that allow inputs in the standard pygame library.